# Kotlin - Check collection contains another collection exactly

Tags: kotlin

I want to be able to check that collection `a` contains **exactly** all of the elements of `b`, but an equality based check is not sufficient; for example:

```
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)

val a = listOf(Person("Alice", 10), Person("Bob", 13))
val b = listOf(Person("Alice", 10), Person("Alice", 10))

fun main() {
   println(a.containsAll(b))
}
```

> true

Whilst this *is technically* `true`, it's not the result I want, because `a` only contains one `Person("Alice", 10)`, whereas `b` contains two of them.

The above example should fail, whilst the below should pass.

```
data class Person(val name: String, val age: Int)

val a = listOf(Person("Alice", 10), Person("Alice", 10), Person("Bob", 13))
val b = listOf(Person("Alice", 10), Person("Alice", 10))

fun main() {
   println(a.containsAllExact(b))
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: In Kotlin you can just do `a == b` for collections. Note that for lists the order will also be taken into account.

Comment: @m0skit0 that returns `false` because of **Bob**, which should be ignored, because I'm not checking for the presence of `b` in `a`.

Comment: @m0skit0 still not the desired result. Converting to sets would only result in `setOf(a, b) == setOf(a)`

Comment: If there are three Alices in `a` and two Alices in `b`, should it still pass?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yes, that should pass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add an extension function for this, something like:

```
fun List<Person>.containsAllExact(list2: List<Person>): Boolean {
    val occurences1 = this.groupingBy{ it }.eachCount()
    val occurences2 = list2.groupingBy{ it }.eachCount()
    return occurences2.all{
        it.value <= occurences1.getOrDefault(it.key, 0)
    }

}
```

Comment: You should look up the `any`, `none`, and `all` functions. But this is *O(n^2)*.

Comment: moved up the count so it isn't repeated, didn't know about the all method, makes it a bit shorter, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One way I can think of is to make a mutable copy of `a`, and try to remove every element of `b`, then check if all elements of `b` can be removed:

```
println(
    a.toMutableList().let { aCopy ->
        b.all(aCopy::remove)
    }
)
```

Or as an extension function:

```
fun <T> Iterable<T>.strictlyContainsAll(other: Iterable<T>) = 
    toMutableList().let { copy -> 
        other.all(copy::remove)
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. I went with the accepted answer because there is no need to create a mutable list, and there were time complexity considerations applied.

Answer (score 1):

<s>I think this would do it</s>

```
println(a.containsAll(b) && (a.size - b.size == (a-b).size))
```

Edit: it doesn't work because it gives false negatives also. for example with

```
val a = listOf(Person("Alice", 10), Person("Alice", 10), Person("Bob", 13))
val b = listOf(Person("Alice", 10))
```

Comment: I'm upvoting because that does work. All of the elements in `b` exist in `a`. A just has one remaining (as per the comments, it should pass).

Comment: @MatthewLayton it returns false in my given example which it shouldn't. In the case that `a` has duplicates that `b` doesn't have it gives the wrong result. But I believe in every other case it should be correct

Comment: Ah, I'm with you (I assumed positive/true from "false negative"). I'll leave the upvote for effort. Thank you :-)